# Commerce Bundle for clothes style

Tags: commerce

The idea behind this module Commerce Bundle is great, i need to use this module in a fashion e-commerce site to enable the user to buy a set of clothes grouped in one style or one look, for example a shirt and a trouser and a jacket, those are separate products, with color and size variations. we need to group blue trouser with white shirt and black jacket in one bundle (style), the problem i face when i need to group those products is the size matter, as when i try to group the products in one bundle i had to select those products also based on size! while actually i don't need the size in bundle. the size will be selected by the user for every product in the bundle when he checkout.

How i can solve this problem?